# how to get trigger to affect triggering object's rigidbody component?

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I've written a script to reset the position of a game object if it passes through a trigger volume. This script works for the most part, so that's great.

However, the object in question retains  its momentum after being reset to its start position.

I added the commented line, which I thought would remove any velocity from the object before resetting the position. No such luck.

The commented line throws an error that I'm trying to control the velocity of an object that does not have a rigidbody component (the trigger itself).

I'm at a loss. How do I affect the rigidbody of object Ball?

```
    #pragma strict

var Ball : GameObject;
var getStartPosition;

function Start () {
    yield WaitForSeconds (0.25);
    Ball = GameObject.Find("Ball");
    getStartPosition = Ball.GetComponent(startPosition).setStartPosition;
    Debug.Log("getStartPosition is set to: "+getStartPosition);
}

function Update () {

}

function OnTriggerEnter (Ball : Collider) {
        //Ball.rigidbody.AddForce(-rigidbody.velocity, ForceMode.VelocityChange);
        Ball.transform.position = getStartPosition;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the `RigidBody` component belongs to the ball.
With `-rigidbody.velocity` you are trying to access the velocity of the trigger.
Try `Ball.rigidbody.velocity` instead.

Btw way, I think you can simply set to zero both `velocity` and `angularVelocity` of the `RigidBody` instead of apply back a force to it.